# Directionality of mincut on a flow network

Tags: algorithm, max-flow

I'm not sure if I have a misunderstanding of mincut, but I've wrote a mincut algorithm using edmond-karps followed by a BFS on the flow network.

If I tell it to do a mincut from A to B, it works, since the residual flow A->B = 0, so it produces the set {A}, with a cut of A->B (1).

However, if I tell it to do a mincut from B to A, it doesn't get to augment any edges (since there are no edges from C), so the resulting set is {C}, with a cut of B->C (2).

The way I see it, I could be misunderstanding this in 1 of 2 ways. Firstly, the mincut from B to A could be correct, as only the edges from B's set would be counted, not the edges to (meaning mincut is asking "what is the minimum to not allow B to connect to A", rather than "what is the minimum to split the graph into 2 partitions).

Or, if you are asked to find mincut on a flow network (a general min-cut, where I'm currently using a "pick an arbitrary source, try all other nodes" method), it must require equal flow in both directions on any edge.

[image: sample graph]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'correct' min-cut for "source=B, sink=A" is 0, since there is no edge B->A (equivalently, c(B, A) = 0); it looks like your implementation might be answering a different question. Are you checking each potential shortest path in the BFS stage to ensure it ends at the sink?

> (meaning mincut is asking "what is the minimum to not allow B to
>   connect to A", rather than "what is the minimum to split the graph
>   into 2 partitions).

Yes, the first one: we only care about bottlenecks from the source to the sink (max-flow min-cut theorem). Min-cut *does* "partition" the graph in two, but there is an additional requirement that the source and the sink are in separate sets.

> (a general min-cut, where I'm currently using a "pick an arbitrary source, try all other nodes" method)

If you are saying "treat all the other nodes as sinks," this is a simple degree calculation on the outward edges of the source.

edit: it's not exactly a degree calculation since the edges are weighted, but it's just adding up edge weights, no search necessary.

> it must require equal flow in both directions on any edge.

No such requirement exists (flow networks are directed graphs - any undirected edges are mapped to two anti-parallel edges, and for a particular flow problem, only one of the edges is used).